# How to access php-fpm from a docker container

Tags: ubuntu, php, docker

I have locally installed nginx and a docker container (https://hub.docker.com/r/phpdockerio/php72-fpm/)

But, how can i access php-fpm socket in a local nginx config?

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  #include fastcgi_params;
  include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

But, seems like `php-fpm:9000` is not working.